# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.myapp.MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting an error in logcat when app is launched.Below is the logcat and java code, i have checked this problem in stackover flow but unable to find the solution.

> MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean toasted = false;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!((MainActivity) getApplicationContext()).toasted) {  (MainActivity.java:28)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ((MainActivity)getApplicationContext()).toasted = true;
        }
}
```

> Logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.counter.MainActivity
        at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
```

Comment: Hi, why are you trying to cast MainActivity to application instead of using `this` instead considering you're already on the activity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean toasted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!toasted) {  
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            toasted = true;
        } 
    }
```

This issue is caused by you attempting to cast an `Application` into an `Activity`.

That's simply not possible because when you're casting, there's certain rules that must be followed.

`Application` and `Activity` can both be cast to a `Context` because they are both children of the `Context` class.

However, if you remember the rules of inheritance in Java, instances of children classes can be cast to their parent class, and an instance of a parent can be cast to its child class **only if** it was originally that child class.

So when you use `getApplicationContext()`, you're getting the context for the `Application` rather than your `Activity`. This is why the cast to `MainActivity` will fail because `MainActivity` is a child of `AppCompatActivity` which is a child of `Activity`, which is completely different from `Application`.

There's also no reason you should require casting to do what you want. You're currently inside the `MainActivity` class, so you have direct access to its instance variables. There's no need to do additional operations to fetch a context, cast it, just to assign a new variable to a variable you already have access to.

Comment: Thank you but when i rotate the screen it is showing toast message again.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. Because when you rotate your device, your Activity is destroyed and recreated again, therefore your `toasted` instance variable is also destroyed and it's reset to `false`. You should add the toasted value to a Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`, then fetch that in your `onCreate()` through `toasted = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(NAME, false);` Make sure you use the same NAME as when you're adding the bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`. This allows your toasted to recover it's previous value prior to the rotation change, so it won't Toast again.

Answer (score 0):

You try to Downcast getApplicationContext() to MainActivity.

getApplicationContext() provide you the Context of the Application and it is not a part of Activity.

If you need to save the variable in your activity just use
this.toasted = true

Comment: When i rotate the screen(horizontal mode) again it is showing toast message

Answer (score 0):

Why are u casting getApplicationContext() to  MainActivity?
You should get the context like this

```
  This.getApplicationContext();
```